# Pass 1 param to multiple screens using expo router (React Native help)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to pass the same params to two different screens, I am using expo router, how can I achieve that?

Here is what I tried but it only passes to "guests" params to the `searchResult` screen but not to the `searchResultMap` screen.

```
<Pressable onPress={() => router.push(
    {pathname: '/home/explore/searchResult', params: {guests: adults + children}},
    {pathname: '/home/explore/searchResultMap', params: {guests: adults + children}})} 
    style={{marginBottom: 20, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:         '#f15454',height: 50, marginHorizontal: 30, borderRadius: 10 }}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}} >Search</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Tried this:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => router.push(
    {pathname: '/home/explore/searchResult', params: {guests: adults + children}},
    {pathname: '/home/explore/searchResultMap', params: {guests: adults + children}})} 
    style={{marginBottom: 20, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:         '#f15454',height: 50, marginHorizontal: 30, borderRadius: 10 }}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}} >Search</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Expecting the guests param to be passed to both screen so I can later deconstruct it using
`const { guests } = useSearchParams();`